# VPS от Amazon (EC2)

Tags: vps, amazon, ec2

Как некоторым известно, на Amazon предоставляется бесплатный EC2 и не только, и вот возникли вопросы:

- в течении первого года 750 часов на каждый месяц то и значат, что
  сервис будет работать круглосуточно независимо от нагрузки?
- Какие есть ограничения?

В случае оплачиваемого тарифа:

- каким образом подсчитывается стоимость использованных услуг за нагрузку cpu, хранилище и передачу данных?

Answer (score 1):

Грузи спокойно свой сервер, используешь 750 часов будешь платить деньги, оплата $0.013 за час на t2.micro