# Ресурсоемкое Web приложение

Tags: веб-программирование, vps

Что лучше выбрать для написания и размещения Web приложения, в котором требуется следующее:

- объемная бд для графов
- реляционная БД(MySQL) также не малого размера(для начала, пару десятков ГБ)
- обработка изображений и другие ресурсоемкие вычисления

По правде, последний год писал приложение на PHP,MySQL и JS разумеется(если точнее, фронт энд с three.js, но и от этого отказался). В силу новых идей и осознанных ошибок хочу пойти, надеюсь, правильным путем.

И на данный момент вопрос стоит в том, на чем же лучше писать бэк энд? Однозначно о *РНР* не может быть речи. Попробовал *nodeJs*, после блокирующих операций пропали восторг и желание разбираться в том, как же избежать блокировки, если понадобится обработать какое-то большое кол-во данных. Писать программку и вызывает через child`_`process ?
Далее есть на примете *Java EE* и *ASP.NET*. На *Java* до этого писал, но представления о *EE* пока не имею. На *C#* также писал, скажем так: эти языки мне одинаково приятны.

Далее выбор состоит в том, где и как размещать приложение? Есть на примете недорогой *VPS*(150 р минимальный), но по началу не хочется платить за то, что большую часть времени сайт будет простаивать. К тому же, если выбор падет на *ASP.NET*, тогда под виндой нужны дополнительно 1000р в месяц, однозначно - нет, в таком случае стоит использовать *Mono* под *Linux*?
Узнал о 12 месячном бесплатном сервисе от *Amazon*, пока подробной информации не нарыл, поэтому есть [несколько вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468603/vps-%D0%BE%D1%82-amazon-ec2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того, с чем я работал, посоветовал бы Node.js или Java.

У Node.js есть проблема с тем, что он однопоточный. Но всегда можно создать несколько инстансов сервиса и потом спрятать за балансер. С другой стороны, в силу однопоточности, будут проблемы с тяжёлыми операциями.

Мы для онлайн игры используем сервисы на Java с использование Netty. Там на каждый запрос срабатывает колбек в отдельном потоке, что не блокирует выполнение запросов от других клиентов. Количество рабочие потоков в пуле можно редактировать. Держит тысячи/десятки тысяч запросов на ура. Для Java есть Hibernate, у него вроде для MySQL весьма хороший драйвер.

ASP.NET громоздкий. Я бы не советовал его использовать.

P.S. вопрос вообще слишком opinion based. Уверен каждый будет советовать ту технологию, с которой работал именно он. В одном, я думаю, большинство согласятся, использовать php точно не стоит.

Comment: я на это и рассчитывал, интересует мнение опытных разработчиков, на основе этого постараюсь сделать выводы

Comment: @Ni55aN проблема в том, что такие вопрос правилами запрещены )

Comment: и зря, на других форумах либо на много больше  неадекватных ответов, либо приходят через неделю) Поэтому этот сервис, имхо, лучший)